# Mint erc20 tokens

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, erc-20

I mint 1,000,000 of tokens (MAX SUPPLY).

I want that 50% of the tokens can be minting like a reward.

I have to send that 500,000 tokens a wallet or i can leave it in the contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the contract is minting tokens, those will be sent to the msg.sender wallet (the person who deployed the contract).

So if you want to use them / send them to your holders, keep them in a wallet.

Also you can create a rescueTokens function that will allow you to withdraw the tokens from your smart contract if you really want to keep them in the contract.

But if you want them to be redistributed automatically you need to build that directly in your contract.